# Quando é que "ordinário" começou a significar mau, vil?

Tags: etimologia

[***Ordinário***](http://www.aulete.com.br/ordin%C3%A1rio) continua a ter alguns dos significados da sua origem latina [***ordinarius***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordinarius): comum, habitual (e.g. *reunião ordinária*). Mas é hoje talvez mais frequentemente usado com o significado de bera, mau caráter, indecoroso e outras coisas pouco edificantes. Por exemplo, *vinho ordinário, homem ordinário*.

Esta evolução não se deu, por exemplo, no inglês, francês ou espanhol. O pior que os cognatos de *ordinário* significam nestas línguas é não se distinguir por qualidade ou nobreza acima do comum, o que está muito longe de ser mau. Por exemplo, um *vino [ordinario](http://dle.rae.es/?w=ordinario&m=form&o=h)* em espanhol é [segundo este site](http://www.vinoseleccion.com/saber-de-vinos/diccionario-del-vino) um vinho comum, sem qualidades específicas ou defeitos destacáveis. [Este site](https://alexissabourin.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/quelle-difference-entre-un-bon-vin-et-un-grand-vin/) distingue entre *vin [ordinaire](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ordinaire/56350?q=ordinaire#55996)* de *mauvais vin*. E uma busca no google revela que *hombre ordinario, homme ordinaire* ou *ordinary man* significam apenas homem comum.

Quando então é que *ordinário* adquiriu o significado pejorativo?

Comment: Ordinário significa também banal ou comum. Não sei quando é que teve início o significado de mau.

Answer (score 6):

Andei a ver o uso da palavra ***ordinário*** neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) e em mais algumas obras disponíveis online, e só na segunda metade do século XIX é que a palavra aparece indubitavelmente com o significado de ***ruim, de má qualidade, vil***. Isto acontece sobretudo nas obras de autores brasileiros, como Bruno Seabra (1837-76), França Junior (1938-90) e Aluísio Azevedo (1857-1913); mas ***ordinário*** mantém o sentido tradicional de ***comum*** em vários dos seus contemporâneos brasileiros e portugueses, como José de Alencar (1829-77), Machado de Assis (1839-1908), Júlio Diniz (1839-71) e Eça de Queiroz (1845-1900). No século XX o significado de ***comum*** mantém-se praticamente apenas em contextos específicos: *acionista ordinário, processo ordinário*.

Em paralelo com alteração do significado de ordinário, o uso de ***ordinariamente*** e ***de ordinário***, com o significado de ***normalmente, habitualmente***, muito comum até ao século XIX, cai a pique no século XX, sendo aparentemente substituído por ***normalmente***, que até então pouco se usara.

**Frequência de alguns advérbios/locuções adverbiais no Corpus do Português**

```
Século                           XVIII    XIX     XX
Ordinariamente, ordinàriamente    168     438      18
De ordinário, de ordinario         77     219      36
Normalmente                         0      12    1760
Habitualmente                       0      35     347
Comumente, comummente              53      14     170
```

Eis dois exemplos do uso de *de ordinário* e *ordinariamente*:

> Pelo meio do dia ***ordinariamente*** Amaro subia à sala de jantar, onde a S. Joaneira e Amélia costuravam. (Eça de Queiroz, *O Crime do Padre Amaro*, 1875.)
>
> Eis a razão por que se escolhem ***de ordinário*** as tardes e as noites de sábado para os casamentos, batizados, bailes, concertos, espetáculos, enfim para tudo quanto é regozijo. (Bernardo Guimarães, *Histórias e Tradições da Província de Minas Gerais*, 1872.)

No século XX, ***ordinariamente*** e ***de ordinário*** não acompanharam a evolução do significado de ***ordinário***. Todas as ocorrências exceto uma (em que *ordinariamente vestida* significa *mal vestida*) mantêm o significado tradicional de *normalmente*. Aparentemente, como *ordináro* deixou geralmente de significar *normal* as pessoas deixaram de usar *ordinariamente*.

Vejamos agora alguns exemplos da evolução do significado de *ordinário*. Até meados do século XIX, no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), *ordinário* significa simplesmente *comum, normal* ou *banal*:

> Aqui houve estes dias alguns casamentos e divórcios, mas isto é tão ***ordinário*** que não merece título de novas. (J. Cunha Brochado, *Cartas*, 1707.)
>
> Notey na Sè da Cidade de Compostella em Galliza, que a imagem de Santiago, que em meyo corpo està no Altar mayor, representa homem quasi agigantado; disseraõ-me, que de tempo muyto antigo era daquelle modo, & he verosimil que se faria representando a estatura do Santo, ou a de qualquer homem ***ordinário*** daquelle tempo. (Antonio de Sousa de Macedo, *Eva e Ave ou Maria Triunfante*, 1734)
>
> Um pai em Portugal que tem três filhos, bomem ***ordinário*** mas cidadao (oficial, por exemplo, ou que tem cem mil reis de renda da sua vinha, olival e jardim) (António Nunes Ribeiro Sanches, *Cartas sobre a educação da mocidade*, 1760)
>
> 1075 — ***Ordinariamente*** o desejo, plano e execução da vingança, incomodam e abalam mais os nossos espíritos do que as injúrias e ofensas recebidas. 1076 — O amor-próprio dos poetas e pintores é sobremaneira irritável; não se contentam com um desagravo ***ordinário***, procuram imortalizar a sua vingança própria. (Mariano José Pereira da Fonseca Maricá, 1773-1848, *Máximas, pensamentos e reflexões*, 1837-41.)
>
> No seu poiso ***ordinário*** ao pé da porta da casa Joaninha com os olhos estendidos, a velha com os ouvidos alerta, devoravam o espaço na direcção de nascente (Almeida Garrett, 1799-1854, *Viagens na Minha Terra*, 1843.)

Ainda se encontra este uso na segunda metade do século XIX:

> E o casamento faz-se, e tudo entra no caminho ***ordinário***, e eu mesmo me hei-de habituar. (Júlio Diniz, 1839-71, *Fidalgos da Casa Mourisca*, 1871.)
>
> Demais, subsídio não é vencimento no sentido ***ordinário***: pro labore. (Machado de Assis, 1839-1908, *Balas de Estado*, 1883-6.)
>
> [Q]ualquer pessoa que encontrasse àquela hora Daniel e o macaco corria risco de morrer de medo. Daniel, extremamente magro e alto, tinha em si um ar lúgubre (…) Calígula, que nos outros dias era um macaco ***ordinário***, tomava, naquelas horas de passeio noturno, um ar tão lúgubre e tão misterioso como o de Daniel. (Machado de Assis, 1839-1908, *Linha Reta e Linha Curva*, 1870)

Na segunda metade do século XIX aparece *ordinário* com sentido claramente pejorativo e sem o sentido de *comum* ou *normal*:

> O homem, mal acabou de ouvir a proposta, folheou um almanaque de defeitos contra o cavalo, rematando por declarar-me que nascera entre cavalos, que com eles tratara até aquela hora, e que, enfim, tomasse-lhe o diabo conta da alma, se não era o meu cavalo o mais ***ordinário*** alazão que ele tinha conhecido. (Bruno Seabra, 1837-76, *Paulo*, 1862.)
>
> MARIA — Em todas as empresas em que te meteste tens dado com os burros n' água. Logo que nos casamos montaste uma grande fábrica de papel. MANUEL — E não era uma boa idéia? MARIA — Segundo os teus cálculos; mas o papel que fizeste foi tão ***ordinário*** que nem para embrulho o quiseram. (França Junior, 1838-90, *As Doutoras*, 1899.)

Noutras passagens, *ordinário* tem o sentido de *qualidade inferior* mas por contraposição a refinado e parece manter também o sentido de *comum*. Isto sugere a via para a evolução do significado. A minoria abastada e refinada considerava o comum como mau.

> Ela, com quem já não iam os imaginosos acepipes da mesa de seu pai, desejou comer do bocado dos trabalhadores, beber do seu vinho ***ordinário*** e palestrar com eles, (Aluísio Azevedo, 1857-1913, *Mistério da Tijuca ou Girândola de Amores*, 1882.)
>
> [S]ustada a sua influência na arte, ficarão as questões à mercê das instintividades desordenadas da turba, que assim achará tudo mau ou tudo bom, conforme lhes bata ou não bata o coração. Desta sorte acontece que os actores portugueses sejam quase todos feitos pelo público ***ordinário***, que os ensaia a tirante das suas apetências grosseiras, tornando-os em meros figurinos duma sensiblerie d' ocasião. (Fialho de Almeida, 1857-1911, *Os Gatos*, 1889-94.)

Mas o mesmo autor que fala negativamente do «público ordinário» é capaz de usar *ordinário* no sentido tradicional, ainda que mesmo assim tenha uma conotação de indesejável:

> Um rico viticultor do Ribatejo um dia disse-me: — Não quero que meu filho seja um homem ***ordinário***, como eu. (Fialho de Almeida, 1857-1911, *Os Gatos*, 1889-94.)

É também na segunda metade do século XIX que se passa a encontrar na literatura *ordinário* como insulto:

> Mas, você é muito ***ordinário!*** exclamou ela com os dentes cerrados. — Podes bramar à vontade! — Um canalha! um valdevinos! um gatuno! — Dize o que quiseres! (Aluísio Azevedo, 1857-1913, *A Condessa Vésper*, 1882.)
>
> — Deixa-me ver o que quer de mim este cabra.. rosnou ele. — Dar-te um banho de fumaça, galego ***ordinário!*** respondeu Firmo (Aluísio Azevedo, 1857-1913, *O Cortiço*, 1890.)

Comment: A mim não me espanta nada que tivesse acontecido, nessa altura, o "ser comum",  era desde logo pejorativo para a alta sociedade. Presumo que tenha vindo dai...

Comment: @JorgeB. Também não me espanta. Mas também não era previsível. Desde tempos imemoriais que uma minoria era riquíssima por comparação da maioria. Já na Roma antiga, e mesmo antes. Porque é que aconteceu no século XIX. E porquê só português e não no espanhol e francês?

Comment: isso é uma boa pergunta que por acaso já fizeste, mas não sei como responder.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nem sei se seria possível responder. E se for, exigiria um livro inteiro. Foi por isso que a minha pergunta foi só, quando é que aconteceu? E mesmo assim deu trabalho.

Answer (score 3):

Quando as diferenças financeiras passaram a ser exorbitantes, quando começou a haver meios de comunicação mais eficientes, onde qualquer coisa de mau que aconteça era espalhado massivamente, o que se tornou comum ouvir noticias ruins, onde 1% da população tem bastante riqueza, e a maioria não. Visto que a palavra comum, pode ser visto como algo que existe bastante. No caso de produtos, quando se refere que um produto é comum, quer dizer que é bastante usado, logo, tem que ser barato, visto que a maioria das pessoas não tem um poder financeiro elevado, e o conceito de coisa barata é quase o mesmo dizer que é ruim (isto não é sempre necessariamente verdade). Moral: Comum = barato = mau.

E nas pessoas, chamar uma pessoa de ordinário no Português do Brasil é o mesmo de dizer que não é uma boa pessoa. Pela mesma questão. É quase o mesmo que dizer "Homem ordinário" ou "Homem é tudo igual". É uma generalização, visto que cada vez mais pessoas são más, ser mau já é comum.

No jornal é mais comum ouvir coisas ruins que boas, na televisão é mais comum ver coisas ruins que boas. E a transformação dessa palavra foi simplesmente uma generalização.

Está é minha reflexão sobre a pergunta questionada, apenas minha opinião. Gostaria muito de debater sobre este assunto.

Comment: Concordo que *ordinário* passasse a significar *ruim* desse modo: de coisa não particularmente acima da média passou a coisa abaixo da média, e progressivamente até coisa ruim. Mas diferenças exorbitantes de riqueza já existem há milénios. Existiam no império romano e continuaram a existir na Europa até hoje. No entanto no latim *ordinarius* não significava ruim. E noutras línguas europeias, *ordinario, ordinnaire, ordinary* nunca passaram a significar ruim. E *comum* também não siginifca ruim. Portanto *ordinário* não passou a significar *ruim* quando apareceram diferenças de riqueza.

Comment: *Homem* e *homem comum* não são nem de perto nem de longe a mesma coisa que *homem ordinário*. Decididamente não em Portugal, e duvido muito que o sejam no Brasil: parece-me que estás com uma visão muito negativa das coisas. De qualquer maneira, não é de agora que o *homem ordinário* significa *homem ruim*.

Comment: Bem, eu dei uma editada para explicar melhor, Portugal foi fundado em 1139, e o Português começou a surgir. E Roma foi fundada em  753 a.C. Então a linguá Portuguesa pode ser considerada uma língua mais recente. E penso que é uma das únicas que da o significado assim. Más fora isso, comum se tornou ruim porque é a verdade. Pelos simples fatos: No jornal é mais comum ouvir coisas ruins que boas, na televisão é mais comum ver coisas ruins que boas. E a transformação dessa palavra foi simplesmente uma generalização. Na minha opnião.